# Extruding a 2D profile using matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 2D profile on Matlab defined in two coordinate vectors, x and y. I would like to specify a thickness for the profile in order to 'extrude it' and transform it into a 3D surface. Just like how CAD programs can extrude a 2D profile to a 3D shape.

This picture explains it perfectly:

[image: Extrusion of a 2D profile]

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: You would need to first know/define what data type you want the extruded surface to be

Comment: It would need to be a point cloud in terms of [X,Y,Z]

Comment: A point cloud filling the volume, the surface or the top surface only? What do you want to do? Just display it?

Comment: @shogun000 but neither the profile nor the extrusion of your exmaple are point clouds, because you connected them, thus it is  structured data

Comment: Just a surface is fine, referring to it as a 'point cloud' is misleading. A representation of the top surface would be sufficient so that I can display it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really need to do anything. Let's say you have the XY coordinates that define the outline, then you assume their Z value is 0, then you create another group of points with the same XY but with Z that is equal to your desired thickness. Viola!

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you all.

Comment: One could also have a look at the following function from file exchange, although it requires faces and vertices and not x,y data: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/70102-convert-2d-triangular-mesh-to-3d-prismatic-mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dev-iL is right. you can do that easily like that:

```
x = randi(100,1,5);
y = randi(100,1,5);
x = x([1:end 1]);
y = y([1:end 1]);
bw = poly2mask(x,y,100,100);
figure;
subplot(121);
plot(x,y)
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(1:100);
zg = bw * 2;
subplot(122);
surf(xg,yg,zg,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp','FaceLighting','gouraud')
material shiny
```

and you get:
[image]

Comment: You can also use surfl function, with colormap gray, which gives similar result as in the question